# Remove scroll event for a ScrollView child

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Is it possible to remove scroll event for a layout that is inside a ScrollView?

I have the following layout hierarchy:

ScrollView

RelativeLayout

LinearLayout

TableLayout

RelativeLayout

GestureOverlayView

I want to remove the scroll event for the RelativeLayout that contains a GestureOverlayView so that when the user draws a vertical line, the event is not intercepted as scroll but as drawing.

Answer (score 3):

I don'y know you still need that or not but here is the answer I tested.
this is how you prevent the parent View from stealing touchEvent of a child view:

```
childView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.childView) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

you can go up in parents by:

```
v.getParent().getParent ....
```